# Is there a .NET library for encoding and decoding google vp8 video?

Tags: .net, video-encoding, decoding, vp8

I need a .NET library for encoding and decoding google vp8 video. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fffmpeg-sharp%2Fsrc

But you may notice that it is in alpha.
However ffmpeg from 0.6 supports vp8

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at it. Have you worked with this api? Any idea how stable it is?